# How can I debug this strange Nuget error? (Error occurred for this query during batch execution)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, nuget

I have a strange error in Nuget package manager. When I click on Updates, and then select our internal package source I get the error: "An error occurred for this query during batch execution. See the inner exception for details", and none of the packages in that list show up.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzL1U.jpg)

It **only seems to happen for certain projects** (not solutions). My coworker tried this for one of those projects and it worked on his machine.

I tried:

1. Cloning a fresh copy of the solution
2. Updating Nuget to the latest version (2.5)
3. Deleting all the packages from that project and reloading

Searching on google was very useless. How can I further debug this error?

**UPDATE:** I ran the command "Get-Package -updates" in the package manager console, and got a bit of extra information:

```
Get-Package : An error occurred for this query during batch execution.  See the inner exception for details.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Package <<<<  -updates
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.GetPackageCommand
```

Comment: Did you try to update your package through the package manager console? Maybe you'll get a meaningful error message. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console#Updating_a_Package

Comment: Well, I wasn't updating a package, just listing the available updates. I just tried doing that in the console, and got more info. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a server error (we had multiple nuget package servers, and the one I was using was out of date).

Comment: What did you do to resolve the issue? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: I went to Options->Package Manager->Package Sources and made sure I was using the new package server instead of the old one.